# Separating the fry from parents - German Blue Ram

Tags: aquarium, safety, breeding, cichlid

If I leave the eggs to hatch with **parents** and let the parents raise the fry, **when** should I take the fries out? I mean, for how long they can live with their parents?

**I know at some point parents will be preparing for the next spawn and will get disturbed by old fries being around them.**